# What kind of opportunities do the Jewish converts obtain with regards to Israel?

Tags: israel

If a highly educated non-Arab Muslim converts to Judaism and learns Hebrew, what kind of opportunity does the state of Israel offer to that person?

Is there anything to expect? Or is it just another person seeking an advantage?

Comment: This question has led to a discussion on [meta](https://expatriates.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/452/is-antisemitism-protected-on-this-site/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The Israeli Law of Return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Return) doesn't define who's considered "a Jew". But, anyone who *is* considered a Jew, is guaranteed permanent residency (and in most cases citizenship) in Israel (with very few exceptions for criminals and security risks).

So if anyone converts into Judaism (no matter from what religion or in what country) and is accepted as "a Jew" by the Israeli government - they can come and settle in Israel under the Law of Return.

The Israeli government usually uses the [Orthodox Judaism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthodox_Judaism) as the source of the interpretation of the question "who's a Jew". The [Jewish Agency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jewish_Agency_for_Israel) is *usually* the one tasked with the actual determination of the eligibility.

The convert needs to undergo a conversion with a Rabbi recognized by the [Israeli Rabbinical Court](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabbinical_Court_(Israel)), and that Rabbi would then be providing the necessary support and attestations for the convert's visa application.

The whole process would probably take many years, Judaism is not known for welcoming converts and is not a missionary religion.

Once in Israel, under the Law of Return, the government provides some assistance (called "assimilation basket") for the first time being but other than that the new immigrant is mostly on their own (although there are a lot of NGOs and religious organizations assisting new immigrants). It will probably be expected for the religious sect in which the new immigrant converted to provide some support as well, although there are no laws on that.

There are no guarantees of a job or a home, and there are duties like serving in the IDF (up to a certain age).

Comment: Please use the chat feature for further comments https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139661/discussion-on-answer-by-littleadv-what-kind-of-opportunities-do-the-jewish-conve